# Error 500 from MVC WebAPI from remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

It seems I'm getting error 500 from server when I am trying to connect to a WebAPI on a remote server with new Windows Server 2016.
I am at wits end here. What could be the cause? WebAPI on other servers are working fine.

```
?response
{StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Pragma: no-cache
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Thu, 02 Jan 2020 07:43:05 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 36
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Expires: -1
}}
    Content: {System.Net.Http.StreamContent}
    Headers: {Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date: Thu, 02 Jan 2020 07:43:05 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
}
    IsSuccessStatusCode: false
    ReasonPhrase: "Internal Server Error"
    RequestMessage: {Method: POST, RequestUri: 'http://url/appname/api/api/Login', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.ObjectContent`1[[appname.BO.AdUserBO, appname.BO, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], Headers:
{
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: 199
}}
    StatusCode: InternalServerError
    Version: {1.1}
```

Comment: Is there anything in Event Viewer? There is no error description here. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is little information for us to go on here. So let's start with the basics

### [The error 500 at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500)

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 500 Internal Server Error server error response code indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> This error response is a generic **"catch-all"** response. Usually, this indicates the server cannot find a better 5xx error code to response. Sometimes, server administrators log error responses like the 500 status code with more details about the request to prevent the error from happening again in the future.

That means that something went wrong that was not expected. Now in WebAPI that could be one of many things:

1. A malformed `web.config`. An easy one to validate
2. An uncaught exception. This could be anywhere in your filters, controllers or app initialization
3. Something that causes 2, like a connectivity that is not in place, access to some api or database that's missing etc.

### Ways to identify the problem

#### Use the Event Viewer

More often than not an error 500 will appear in your event viewer.

#### Use the [IncludeErrorDetailPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh834230(v%3Dvs.118))

In `Application_Start` - Global.asax file

```
var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
```

#### Create custom [Exception logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling)

If you want to add more information, hide stacktrace partially or create your own configuration, there are some ways to do it from WebApi 2

> **Exception loggers** are the solution to seeing all unhandled exception caught by Web API.
>
> **Exception handlers** are the solution for customizing all possible responses to unhandled exceptions caught by Web API.
>
> **Exception filters** are the easiest solution for processing the subset unhandled exceptions related to a specific action or controller.